# Spring amqp: detect shutdown and reconnect to another queue

Tags: spring-amqp

We have this setup where we call a webservice to create a queue, and receive the queue name from the response.

Then we set up a SimpleMessageListenerContainer and set the queue name there, and then start it.

However, from time to time, the queue is deleted - resulting in a "*404 could not declare queue XXXXXXXXX*" error. In these cases, I need to call the webservice again and add the new QueueName to the SimpleMessageListenerContainer and then removing the old one.

The only way I figured out trigger any code to handle this was to create a custom CachedConnectionFactory and overriding the shutdownCompleted method.

However, shutdownCompleted seems to trigger when the SimpleMessageListenerContainer switches over as well, so it sticks in a loop. The ShutdownSignalException sent into shutdownCompleted does not seem to look any different if the trigger is external from the server or from the client handling the new queue, so I can't figure out how to skip the handling on the "second" go.

So what is the usual way to detect and run custom handling when the server kills the queue?

Answer (score 0):

The container publishes a `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` when the listener fails.

Add an `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent>`, stop the container, change the queues and restart.

You will likely get multiple events because, by default, the container will try to reconnect 3 times before giving up and stopping itself.