# How to restart a SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

I try to connect to a RabbitMQ with spring boot. The connection should always restart/retry the connection. I have a problem reconnecting after a fatal exception. The application can never loose a connection and not indefinitely   retry to get a connection.

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        final SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(getConnectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setQueues(getQueue());
        listenerContainer.setDeclarationRetries(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        final AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSpec adapter = (AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSpec) Amqp.inboundAdapter(listenerContainer);
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(adapter)
                .filter(filter)
                .transform(transformer)
                .handle(processor)
                .get();
    }
```

I may get a `fatal` Exception which I catch in a `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent>`. This exception is not always the same, the last time it was a 'PossibleAuthenticationFailureException'

If the exception is fatal I stop and then start the container. I realize this may be the wrong place, as it looks like the container is stopped after calling of the event.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
    if (event.isFatal()) {
      SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) event.getSource()
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.stop();
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.start();
      LOG.info("started container");
    }
}
```

resulting in the following output and a no connection to the rabbit. (After the following output nothing follows, it just does nothing is not connected)

> [rContainer#0-34] startConnectionOnFatalConnectionListener : started container.
>
> [rContainer#0-34] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer

Versions:

- RabbitMQ 3.6.8, Erlang 19.2
- Spring Integration (spring-integration-amqp): 4.3.9

I was able to get more log entries, the following lines get logged before the ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent is called:

```
07:05.843 ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
07:05.843 ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
07:15.087 ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer received fatal exception on startup

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerStartupException: Authentication failure
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1280) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:65) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:309) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:472) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:342) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:813) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:767) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:887) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:300) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:234) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:212) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:327) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:542) ~[amqp-client-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Workaround: Implement a health check. The health check checks if the connection to rabbitMQ exists. The application get's restarted if the health check doesn't succeed. (Implemented as a cron, which calls a bash scripts. The bash scripts stops and start the container).

Comment: what is the fatal exception? Can you add the event listener ?

Comment: @Diyoda_ i clarified, if you still have any question don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: First of all you can't do that there in the listener. It becomes too late, because the container is stopped afterwards by the `aborted` reason. In other words your `start()` is overridden by the subsequent container's `stop()`. On the other hand if `event.isFatal()`, it is unrecoverable situation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#consumer-events

Comment: @ArtemBilan when&how would you do it? An unrecoverable situation for the application is unacceptable, is it possible to replace the container from there or do something else? I can't find anything in the documentation regarding fatal events, except that the container will restart for non fatals.

Comment: maybe I don't understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203861/spring-amqp-detect-shutdown-and-reconnect-to-another-queue  correctly but this suggest that I may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) that, according to the docs,

> [...] is fully self-recovering in case the broker is temporarily unavailable, and allows for stops/restarts as well as runtime changes to its configuration.

Comment: We're using https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html (amqp), that doesn't seem like a replacement to me. How would you replace it with the DefaultMessageListenerContainer (jms)?

Comment: sorry, I read too fast. but maybe you could have a look at the way the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java) implements its recovery process ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you would want to consider here. First is the fact that an event listener is to late. You would want to encase the calling code in an error handler. And since you are getting different errors and you just want to catch them all and do they same thing, you would want to do a generic error handler. One that catches everything and handles it the same way. You have specific handlers. Here is an example of a generic error handler.

```
try
{
     //statements that may cause an exception
}
catch (exception(e))‏
{
     //error handling code
}
```

Good Luck and I hope it works out for you.